# undefined method `keys' for #<Cucumber::Messages::GherkinDocument::Feature:0x0801ea30> (NoMethodErr or)

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, parallel-processing, cucumber

Facing problem when try to run 'parallel_tests' in Cucumber + Ruby framework.
Command which I use:

```
bundle exec parallel_cucumber -n 3 features/someFeature --group-by scenarios
```

Error I get:

```
undefined method `keys' for #<Cucumber::Messages::GherkinDocument::Feature:0x07fba0b0> (NoMethodErr
or)
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:81:
in `rubify_keys'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:32:
in `initialize'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:125
:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:106
:in `new'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:106
:in `feature'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:17:
in `feature'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:32:in `d
ocument'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:30:in `block in parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:21:in `compile'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:75:in `run!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
undefined method `keys' for #<Cucumber::Messages::GherkinDocument::Feature:0x07f959d8> (NoMethodErr
or)
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:81:
in `rubify_keys'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:32:
in `initialize'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:125
:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:106
:in `new'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:106
:in `feature'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:17:
in `feature'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:32:in `d
ocument'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:30:in `block in parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:21:in `compile'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:75:in `run!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
undefined method `keys' for #<Cucumber::Messages::GherkinDocument::Feature:0x07f5db90> (NoMethodErr
or)
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:81:
in `rubify_keys'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:32:
in `initialize'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:125
:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:106
:in `new'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:106
:in `feature'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/ast_builder.rb:17:
in `feature'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:32:in `d
ocument'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:30:in `block in parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:29:in `parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:21:in `compile'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:75:in `run!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

Thing I want is to run **different** scenarios in different processes to minimize tests running time.

- Cucumber version 3.2.1
- Ruby version 2.6.0
- parallel_tests 3.0
- cuke_modeler 3.1.0
- cucumber-gherkin 14.0.1

**Update**
After updating cucumber to 4.1 I get another error

```
Empty stack (RuntimeError)
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-tag-expressions-2.0.4/lib/cucumber/tag_expressions/parser.rb:132:in `pop'

C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-tag-expressions-2.0.4/lib/cucumber/tag_expressions/parser.rb:77:in `push_
expression'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-tag-expressions-2.0.4/lib/cucumber/tag_expressions/parser.rb:24:in `parse
'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:85:in `match_single_tag_express
ion?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:47:in `block in match_tags?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:47:in `all?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:47:in `match_tags?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/tag_filter.rb:11:in `test_case'

C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/compiler.rb:27:in `pickle'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:27:in `block in document'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:38:in `yield'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:38:in `block (
3 levels) in messages'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:37:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:37:in `block (
2 levels) in messages'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:79:in `yield'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:79:in `block (
2 levels) in sources'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:78:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:78:in `block i
n sources'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:25:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:25:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:25:in `block i
n messages'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:21:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:21:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:21:in `document'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:33:in `block in parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:32:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:32:in `parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:24:in `compile'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:79:in `run!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:29:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
Empty stack (RuntimeError)
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-tag-expressions-2.0.4/lib/cucumber/tag_expressions/parser.rb:132:in `pop'

C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-tag-expressions-2.0.4/lib/cucumber/tag_expressions/parser.rb:77:in `push_
expression'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-tag-expressions-2.0.4/lib/cucumber/tag_expressions/parser.rb:24:in `parse
'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:85:in `match_single_tag_express
ion?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:47:in `block in match_tags?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:47:in `all?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:47:in `match_tags?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/tag_filter.rb:11:in `test_case'

C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/compiler.rb:27:in `pickle'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:27:in `block in document'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:38:in `yield'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:38:in `block (
3 levels) in messages'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:37:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:37:in `block (
2 levels) in messages'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:79:in `yield'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:79:in `block (
2 levels) in sources'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:78:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:78:in `block i
n sources'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:25:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:25:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:25:in `block i
n messages'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:21:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:21:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:21:in `document'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:33:in `block in parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:32:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:32:in `parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:24:in `compile'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:79:in `run!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:29:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
Empty stack (RuntimeError)
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-tag-expressions-2.0.4/lib/cucumber/tag_expressions/parser.rb:132:in `pop'

C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-tag-expressions-2.0.4/lib/cucumber/tag_expressions/parser.rb:77:in `push_
expression'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-tag-expressions-2.0.4/lib/cucumber/tag_expressions/parser.rb:24:in `parse
'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:85:in `match_single_tag_express
ion?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:47:in `block in match_tags?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:47:in `all?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:47:in `match_tags?'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/tag_filter.rb:11:in `test_case'

C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/compiler.rb:27:in `pickle'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:27:in `block in document'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:38:in `yield'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:38:in `block (
3 levels) in messages'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:37:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:37:in `block (
2 levels) in messages'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:79:in `yield'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:79:in `block (
2 levels) in sources'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:78:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:78:in `block i
n sources'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:25:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:25:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-gherkin-14.0.1/lib/gherkin/stream/parser_message_stream.rb:25:in `block i
n messages'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:21:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:21:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:21:in `document'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:33:in `block in parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:32:in `each'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:32:in `parse'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/core.rb:24:in `compile'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:79:in `run!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:29:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cucumber-4.1.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby26/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Seems that something went wrong with dependencies and versions.
Combination of:

- cucumber (3.1.2)
- parallel_tests (2.32.0)
- NO cuke_modeler AT ALL

works fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

Your original combination of dependencies was transitively including both the `gherkin` gem and the `cucumber-gherkin` gem, which cannot co-exist (see https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/1063). Upgrading your `cucumber` from 3.x to 4.x as you did should have solved the problem but, presumably, you still had `gherkin` in your dependency tree somewhere (without seeing your `Gemfile.lock`, it's difficult to tell).

Regarding your final dependency set, I can say with great confidence (I wrote the dang thing after all) that the presence of the `cuke_modeler` gem would not, on its own, cause a problem and that it has been both used and tested with both `cucumber` and `parallel_tests`. Additionally, `cuke_modeler` can work with either `gherkin` or `cucumber-gherkin`. You just have to be sure to use `cuke_modeler` 2.x if you are using `gherkin` and to use `cuke_modeler` 3.x if you are using `cucumber-gherkin`. If adding `cuke_modeler` back into your final set of dependencies causes a problem, I would again start by looking at your transitive dependencies and see if the `gherkin`/`cucumber-gherkin` conflict is present.